# Forward-declaring a C-Struct yields "incompatible types"-warning

Tags: c, typedef, forward-declaration

I have some functions that use the forward-declared type `A`:

```
typedef struct AImpl A;

void fun(A* a);
```

Later on a library is included which defines a type  `B` and a function to generate it:

```
struct B {
  /*...*/
};
struct B* newB(void) {
  /*...*/
}
```

At last, I define the type `A` as this type `B` and use it:

```
typedef struct B AImpl;

void fun(A* a) {
  a = newB();
}
```

This however generates a warning:

> '=': incompatible types - from 'B *' to 'A *'

Is there a way to forward-declare a type that is compatible with `B` (in this example `A`), without...

- forward-declaring `B` itself
- including the library before declaring the functions that use `A`
- having to cast the result of `newB()` to `A*`

?

Comment: `typedef struct AImpl A;` and `typedef struct B AImpl;` do not make `A` and `B` the same type. `struct AImpl` is very different from `AImpl`. `B` is not a type at all (`struct B` is).

Comment: You have a `struct AImpl` that you typedef to another name. Then you have a `struct B` that want to typedef to `AImpl`. Now, what is what?

Comment: @n.1.8e9 Thanks for the clarification of my misunderstanding, I understand now why my approach wasn't working. To rephrase my question, is there a way to have a `struct B`-compatible type before `struct B` is defined, without forward-declaring `struct B` itself?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Why not just forward-declare it?

Comment: First, it is not clear why you want to declare `fun` before including the library header. Just include the library header and then declare `fun`. Second, if you want `fun` to take a pointer to the `struct B` that the library header will declare, then you can simply forward-declare `struct B;`, followed by `void fun(struct B *a);`. You could even do `typedef struct B A; void fun(A *a);`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9 @Eric The definition and name of type `struct B` is system-dependent, so if I had to forward-declare it I would have to do if for every system, which I would like to avoid. 
The function `fun` is on a higher abstraction layer, where I would like to not have to differentiate between different systems yet.

Comment: You cannot avoid mentioning the struct name *somewhere*, and you must do it for every system. You might just as well mention it before it is used.